# Is it possible to filter on a non-indexed field with doc_values=true in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, search, lucene, information-retrieval, elasticsearch-5

In Elasticsearch 5.6 using the following mapping:

```
"category" => [
    "type"=>"keyword",
    "doc_values"=>true,
    "index"=>false
    "store"=>true
]
```

I was given advice that it was possible to write a query that filters on this field because of its doc_values setting, even though the index attribute was set to false, but it seems like doc_values fields are only useful for aggregations and sorting.

Is it possible to create a query which filters on this field?

Comment: If the field is not indexed, it won't be searchable.

Comment: Thanks @AndreiStefan, if you can write this as an answer I'd be happy to award it to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An field that is not indexed is, [by definition](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/mapping-index.html), not searchable. Elasticsearch won't put it in the inverted index (which is used for searching). If you try to run a search query, you will get an error like `Cannot search on field [category] since it is not indexed.`

Comment: Thanks, if I perform a term search on "category.keyword" I don't get the error, just zero results (when I'm matching against an exact value that I know exists). Is that still the expected behavior when the field isn't in the inverted index? A consultant left this mapping with documentation saying one could filter on the field, I'm just trying to figure out if I'm missing something since, as you say, by definition it shouldn't be possible.

Comment: What is the complete mapping of the category field? Sub-fields included

Comment: It's the same as listed in the question, except there is also a "copy_to"=>"TIER1" attribute. TIER1 has a range of analyzers etc and it acts as a grouping of several fields that can be searched and boosted as one. My understanding is that this provides free text search against all those fields as a collective, but only if you search the TIER1 field explicitly. I assume it doesn't influence searching against the category field explicitly and therefore doesn't provide a way to filter on that field. Also, if I search against "category" rather than "category.keyword" I get the error you mentioned

Comment: This is why I asked for the complete mapping. The `.keyword` part should have its own mapping. To get the full, real mapping of the index run `GET /index_name/_mapping`.

Comment: The field mapping is:
          "category" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "index" : false,
            "store" : true,
            "copy_to" : [
              "TIER1"
            ]
          },
There is no further mapping information for the keyword part, just the "type": "keyword" attribute.

Comment: That's impossible. You are not looking at the right mapping. Elasticsearch doesn't have any "hidden" fields and your `category` field full mapping probably looks like this `"category": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "doc_values": true,
          "index": false,
          "store": true,
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }`

Comment: Or, there is no sub-field for `category` and you are wrongly assuming that `category` has a "hidden" `keyword` field. When you search on `category.keyword` and you get nothing back is like searching on a non-existent field. You can simply search on `category.blabla` and you'll get the same outcome.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help and patience on this question. There is no sub field so this mapping is just incorrect and cannot be used as the consultant indicated.

Answer (score 0):

[Keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) datatypes have [doc_values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/doc-values.html) enabled by default. You don't need to enable it explicitly. And keyword fields can be filtered in query if the exact text is searched. 
For e.g., I have following index with mapping

```
PUT index_name
{
  "mappings": {
    "type_name": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sample document:

```
{
    "id":1,
    "name":"hatim"
}
```

So, I can search by filtering it like this in query part

```
GET index_name/type_name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "name": "hatim"
    }
  }
}
```

And so on, you can add aggregation over it like this

```
GET index_name/type_name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "name": "hatim"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "count": {
      "value_count": {
        "field": "name"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do these searches by keyword work even when "index" is set to false in the mapping?

Comment: You don't need to define any other options when you define the field type as "keyword". By default for "keyword" datatypes, the doc_values is true, index is true and store is false. See my updated answer with index mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use indexes to filter a field that is not indexed, of course. But, in some cases, you may know that the data volume is low (since you filtered the data with other indexed fields likes time or else) and still want to return only a subset of the filtered data with the help of another not indexed field.

In this case, and only this case, you may use scripted filters:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": """
            double amount = doc['amount'].value;
            if (doc['type'].value == 'expense') {
              amount *= -1;
            }
            return amount < 10;
          """
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

See [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html) for more informations on the trade off it implies.